# How to watch for changes for all collections in a database with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, changestream

I am trying to watch for realtime changes in all of the collections in a MongoDB database. I am following pymongo docs at  https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.watch but it seems to only work for individual collection not the whole database:

```
import pymongo 

uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myDBName'  
db = client[myDBName]  
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

    try:
            with db.watch(
                    [{'$match': {'operationType': 'insert'}}]) as stream:
                for insert_change in stream:
                    print(insert_change)
            
    except Exception as e:
            print('OOPS!! Some ERROR Occurred')
            print(e)
```

but I get the following error:

```
{aggregate: 1} is not valid for '$changeStream'; a collection is required., full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1614185450, 3), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "{aggregate: 1} is not valid for '$changeStream'; a collection is required.", 'code': 73, 'codeName': 'InvalidNamespace', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1614185450, 3), 'signature': {'hash': b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'keyId': 0}}}
```

when I change it to `db.myCollectionName.watch()...` it is working however. What am I doing wrong? I tried using a loop through all collections and watch for each, but that only watches for the first collection in database and not entire range of `for collection in collections:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a new enough MongoDB server that supports this functionality.

Comment: Yes, that is likely the reason, but can't test to confirm because the latest version of mongoDb that can be installed on WSL2 is 3.6. I am trying to figure if I can find a way to try version 4.4.1, so far no luck...

Comment: I managed to set up the replicasets with docker-compose and mongodb version 4.2, and yes, that was the thing. It's working now!